# How to read specific lines in XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have two files, `C:\Old\test.xml` and `C:\New\Test.xml`.
They are written in two versions, so I need to determine which version before traversing the file nodes.

The header information of `C:\Old\Test.xml`:

```xml
<?OurCompanyName ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fieldref.xsl"?>
<ROOT ThisVersion="2.2.91">
```

The header information of `C:\New\Test.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?OurCompanyName?>
<Project xmlns:ThisVersion="6.0.55.0">
```

Some members are using the new version, some are using the old, but they are in the same location, so I need to read the version and branch accordingly.
I'm currently doing:

```bsh
[xml]$ETLFile = Get-Content C:\New\Test.xml
```

What I'd like to know is how I can read in either file and say: 
If `ThisVersion` is 6 or greater do whatever, else to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the value of the attribute `ThisVersion` to a `version` object and check its `Major` property:

```
if (([version]$ETLFile.DocumentElement.ThisVersion).Major -ge 6) {
  # do some
} else {
  # do other
}
```